# Quotienting out by a normal subgroup to get a Perfect Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

For the first part, If you have a homomorphic image that is a solvable group, then from the solvable group, we can induce another homomorphism which has a homomorphic image that is abelian. Solvable groups have normal series that have abelian quotients, so simply consider the quotient homomorphism with the first normal subgroup in the normal series.

For part 2: Not entirely sure how to do this one.  I think you have to consider $G/H\to S$. but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.  Also in general, how do you even show A group is the composite of two of it's subgroups?

Source:https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/363/docs/F17_510ab.pdf

Comment: If $NH\neq G$, then $G/NH$ is a nontrivial quotient of $G/H$, but it is also isomorphic to a nontrivial quotient of $\theta(G)$, which is a subgroup of a solvable group. You should be able to deduce from that and the first part that this is impossible, giving you that $NH$ must equal all of $G$. P.S. it's not "composite of two of it's subgroups", it "product of two of its subgroups".